# Why do Access Reports have Form Event Macro Properties?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-reports

While enumerating the properties collection of an Access Report in Access 2013 (ACCDB), I find properties with names that *probably* shouldn't be there, as they're the names of properties that are for use with Access Forms.

- AfterDelConfirmEmMacro
- AfterFinalRenderEmMacro
- AfterInsertEmMacro
- AfterLayoutEmMacro
- AfterRenderEmMacro
- BeforeDelConfirmEmMacro
- BeforeInsertEmMacro
- BeforeQueryEmMacro
- BeforeRenderEmMacro
- BeforeScreenTipEmMacro
- CommandBeforeExecuteEmMacro
- CommandCheckedEmMacro
- CommandEnabledEmMacro
- CommandExecuteEmMacro
- DataChangeEmMacro
- DataSetChangeEmMacro
- OnConnectEmMacro
- OnDeleteEmMacro
- OnDirtyEmMacro
- OnDisconnectEmMacro
- PivotTableChangeEmMacro
- QueryEmMacro
- SelectionChangeEmMacro
- ViewChangeEmMacro

Is this some error in the Access object model, or are these properties genuinely available within Reports? Or have I just got a corrupt report?